# Windows 7 clean install, freezes when starting programs

Tags: windows-7, freeze

I have a problem on a brand new Windows 7 Lenovo T510 intel I5/4gb ram.
When I got the Laptop, right off the bat i noticed that it would freeze up often on th most simple tasks.
After a while I got fed up and reinstalled. 
All that is installed currently is AVG/Firefox/Office.

I Rebooted after installing those things and when I try to open Firefox it freezes just trying to open. Ive tried a few other things and it freezes all the time.

Any Ideas what it could be?

Comment: When it freezes, does it ever UNFREEZE?  Or are these hard lockups and you have to reboot the machine?

Comment: most of the time its one or two progs that freeze up and then explorer becomes unresponsive. then I reboot

Answer (score 2):

Its possibly a memory failure. or a bad sector on the hard disk where some vital win7 files are kept. If you can burn a CD on another computer, I'd recommend downloading memtest x86 to see if there are any problems with your memory. If after all this it doesnt work, I'd call Lenovo.

link to Memtest 86 : http://www.memtest.org/#downiso

Comment: I checked the memory and its fine, I have the feeling its the HDD maybe, but SMART-reporting looks good.

Answer (score 1):

First thing would be to run the Lenovo Diagnostics on the machine.  You can download them (I think its called the Thinkvantage toolbox) or they may have sent you a disc with the computer.  That will test common components, and let you know if any parts are faulty.

Also, we have had some T410 laptops overheat, how warm is your case?

Comment: Toolbox is installed from the factory - just hit the blue button.

Answer (score 0):

Does it freeze/lock up in safe mode or if you go into the bios and leave it running?  That help to narrow down issue as well.